# How to create patch for a new file, and patch it back to the original directory?

Tags: diff, patch

Suppose I have a directory dir1, and have files f1.c and f2.c in it.
I copy all to directory dir2, modify both f1 and f2, and add a new file f3.c.

Then I do the diff to create patch:
diff -ruN dir1/ dir2/ > diff.patch

Now I want to apply the patch back to dir1. However the changes in f1 and f2 are successfully patched. but I don't get a new file f3.c in dir1:

[/local/home/tmp]$ patch -p0 < diff.patch 
patching file dir1/f1.c
Hunk #1 succeeded at 1 with fuzz 2.
patching file dir1/f2.c
The next patch would create the file dir2/f3.c,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored

How to apply the patch, so that I can add f3.c in dir1 too?

Answer (score 0):

OK, i've figured out, that you must cd into dir1, and use the -p1 parameter: 
cd dir1 
patch -p1 < ../diff.patch